# Does Apple's school manager allow for buying In-App purchases in bulk?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm releasing an app and considering opting in to this option

> "Offer a reduced price on the Apple School Manager for volume purchase"

My app however runs on a In-app purchasable subscription, so this option may be irrelevant. All the info I can find says that it works for one-time purchase apps, but no info in regards to IAP's. The only way to really find out it seems, would be to create a school manager account, which would require "enrolling an organization".

Does anyone know if Apple's School Manager allows for IAP purchasing in bulk?

Comment: Apple school manager and apple business manager can't make in app purchases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paulw11 answered my question

> Apple school manager and apple business manager can't make in app purchases.